# How to check for an interface implementation in F#

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

Assuming I have these types (forgive the C# syntax, I'm new to F#):

```
interface I { }
class A { }
class B : A, I { }
```

In C# I can do this:

```
A a = …
bool isI = a is I;
```

However, in F#, having this:

```
let a : A = ...
```

I know that `a` may contain an instance of `B` and implement `I`. However, this results in a compile error saying `A` is not compatible with `I`:

```
let isI = a :? I
```

However, this works:

```
let isI = a :> obj :? I
```

How come? `a :? I` is neither an upcast nor a downcast, sure. But how does it work with obj? Do interfaces somehow count as object subclasses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is hinted in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/symbol-and-operator-reference/):

> Returns `true` if the value matches the specified type (including if it is a subtype); otherwise, returns `false` (type test operator).

If you refer to [the spec](https://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.1/FSharpSpec-4.1-latest.pdf) in *7.9 Dynamic Type-Test Patterns*, it confirms this is a compile-time constraint:

> An error occurs if *type* cannot be statically determined to be a subtype of the type of the pattern input

The interface is 'higher' in the hierarchy, it's *not* `A` or a subtype of `A`.

In mucn the same way, this doesn't compile either:

```ml
let isObj = a :? obj
```

By upcasting to `obj` first, you can then check if the type is `I`, as this is a subtype of `obj`.

Comment: Isn't this... counterintuitive? Is there a type check operator that's an exact equivalent of C#'s `is`?

Comment: @Arshia001 not that I'm aware of. This sort of type checking isn't too common in F# (except when dealing with C# interop). In the times I have used this operator, I've not come across this issue, so I can only conclude it's most common to check for subtypes.

Comment: Interop indeed. Thanks!

Comment: I disagree that the documentation answers the question: it refers to testing whether the _value_ (`a` in this case) matches the specified type (`I` in this case), not whether the expression's static type does, and does not indicate any limitations on which types might be used for such tests.

Comment: @kvb that's probably a reasonable interpretation. However, it *does* seem to have a limitation in line with this. Is there anywhere that is explicitly documented (I've tried and failed to find anything else).

Comment: @kvb found confirmation in the spec & have updated the answer to include it.

Comment: @CharlesMager - The F# specification is usually the place to look for definitive answers (though it doesn't always indicate _why_ the behavior is specified as it is).  In this case, the rules are laid out in section 6.7.3 (Dynamic Type-Test Expressions) of the F# spec.